# Getting Docker API 500 error when running bootBuildImage

Tags: spring-boot, docker, paketo

We have recently started to use Gradle's bootBuildImage task for building docker images. Locally we can build images successfully without any issues, however our Jenkins build sometimes randomly fails with following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dockerTestImage:bootBuildImage'.
> Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/pack.local/builder/zuslfxipuv:latest?force=1' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "unrecognized image ID sha256:xxxxx"
```

Running the build again solves the issue. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Versions used in the project:

- spring-boot version: 2.5.0
- jdk version: 11
- gradle version: 6

Comment: is the docker server running?

Comment: yes, it's running. And when we are replaying the build, the issue disappears.

Comment: We've identified an issues with Spring Boot that can cause this problem when more than one build is run at exactly the same time. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27888. Is it possible this is only happening for you when more than one build runs in parallel?

Comment: Yes, we have noticed that this error appears when running builds in parallel. Thank you for the link to the issue!

Comment: Thanks for confirming. We'll get a fix in for the next round of Spring Boot releases. Subscribe to the GitHub issue for updates.